# What's the best way to animate something in canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm trying to animate a triangle "flipping" in canvas using javascript. The problem is that javascript performs the animation too fast and you can't really see the effect. What's the best way to "slow it down". I've tried the setTimeout function but it doesn't work because it delays the execution of the function to redraw my triangle but continues with the execution of the redraw loop, if that makes any sense. Are there any jQuery functions to delay execution> I saw the delay() function but I don't think that's applicable in this case?  Let me show you what I have as of now:

http://jsfiddle.net/hnqB6/7/

Any suggestions welcome :)

Comment: Actually just found out about setInterval. Managed to get it working. Here's the code if anyone ever needs it:

http://jsfiddle.net/hnqB6/8/

Thanks for reading!

Comment: also take a look at requestAnimationFrame, which would improve your solution

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The answer I provided does just what I wanted I only have a small problem that if you click on one of the canvases and then, before the animation has finished you click on another one, it messes up. Any idea on how to fix that? http://jsfiddle.net/hnqB6/10/

Comment: Feel free to answer you own question below, and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for the answer. I use setInterval to for the animation and the data() jQuery function to allow the animation to store data about each canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/kerrmarin/V8Dme/1/